# Python ubuntu apache кодировка ответа

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, веб-программирование, apache2

Добрый день
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Ubuntu 16.04, apache2, python3.6
Везде кодировка установлена utf-8, в консоли python после json.dumps() возвращает нормальный массив, кодируются русские буквы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но если же запрашивать выполнение из браузера(неважно под какой системой) то ответ приходит вот в таком виде[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам скрипт банально читает содержимое папки и отдает в виде json массива.

локаль системы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема, что я упустил?

P.S.: с ubuntu общаюсь недавно, совсем недавно)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=u0441

Comment: @alexanderbarakin всё немного интереснее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=udcd0